# Flutter This function has a return type of 'Future<bool>', but doesn't end with a return statement

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using this method and I get this message. How can I correct it?

> This function has a return type of 'Future', but doesn't end with a return statement.
>   Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');}

return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: _onWillPop,
    child: Scaffold
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your must `return` `bool` from `_onWillPop()`

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop() { 

  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
  return true;// or false as per your need

}
```